# ASP.NET Identity 2 UserManager get all users async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Can somebody tell if there is a way to get all users async in ASP.NET Identity 2?

In the `UserManager.Users` there is nothing async or find all async or somwething like that

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is no way to do this asynchronously with the `UserManager` class directly. You can either wrap it in your own asynchronous method: (this might be a bit evil)

```
public async Task<IQueryable<User>> GetUsersAsync
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return userManager.Users(); 
    }
}
```

Or use the `ToListAsync` extension method:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        return await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Or use your context directly:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        return await context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You opened my eyes! I wass missing a reference to `System.Data.Entity` in order to get the `ToListAsync()` extension method. Great, works perfect ...

Comment: "There is no way to do this asynchronously with the UserManager class directly"... your second example is exactly how the API designers intended it to be called.

Comment: If using .ToListAsync() extension I also needed to add this using `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: For me with `MongoDb` the @DavidG's first solution works. Otherwise, `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` is the solution.