# Definition without GetAwaiter (Razor, MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, async-await, task

I got below class:

```
public class AllRegistrationsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
 private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> um;
 private readonly MyContext myContext;

 public AllRegistrationsViewComponent(UserManager<IdentityUser> um, MyContext myContext)
 {
   this.um = um;
   this.myContext= myContext;
 }

 public async Task<IViewComponentResult> Invoke()
 {
   var allUsers= await um.Users.ToList();
   return View(allUsers);
 }
}
```

And I'm getting below message:

```
List <IdentityUser> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter and no accessible method 
GetAwaiter accepting a first argument of type List<IdentityUser> could be found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Identity 2 UserManager get all users async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357676/asp-net-identity-2-usermanager-get-all-users-async)

Comment: as well thanks Nathan for link

Comment: @Rob, just corrected, thanks for note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line from

```
 var allUsers= await um.Users.ToList();
```

To

```
var allUsers= await um.Users.ToListAsync();
```